# Read bluetooth data with MIT App Inventor

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, app-inventor

Arduino Uno, using an HC-05 Bluetooth module with default settings, sends either a 0 or a 1 byte via its RX/TX pins (pins 0 and 1).

```
Serial.write(1);
Serial.write((byte) 0);
```

Using the app 'Bluetooth Terminal', I can see the data coming in neatly. Testing with Serial.print strings shows it works. And with Serial.write, I see the expected gibberish when it tries converting to text.

I want to make an app with MIT App Inventor to show a green screen if the data is 0 and a red screen if the data is 1. This is what I made, after reading every possible tutorial:

[Block diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka1tg.png)
[image]

After pairing, I start the app, using the AI2 Companion, but it gives me a blank screen. I cannot even select the HC-05 from the list.

Would anyone have an idea what is wrong?
Could anyone also shed some light on the bit of my code where I try toggling between images based on whether the module sends a 0 or a 1?

Please note the Arduino code can send anything. I chose bytes because I only need boolean logic and App Inventor has a ReceiveUnsigned1ByteNumber function.

Comment: are you sure, you enabled bluetooth? [How to enable Bluetooth (User still needs to confirm)](https://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#2enableBT)